# I contain what's in a bleaker war

Tags: riddle

> I contain what's in a bleaker war,
>
> Figures entered and values stored.
>
> Within your eyes I keep the watch running,
>
> With light I can rise if I let the sun in.
>
> Stored within all that's alive,
>
> When lost and replaced you might just survive.
>
> Distances covered without moving a fraction,
>
> It's time to break off and take our own action.

**What am I?**

---

***Edit:*** A very quick, non-specific clue... Every line can be individually applied to the "what am I?".

Comment: You guys seem to get them a bit too easy for my liking.

Hopefully this one's not too easy! :)

Comment: Without the second verse to that riddle, I'd have an answer. That's the only part throwing me off.

Comment: @Adam, I'm very tempted to ask you what you thought it might be but it won't be in a spoiler tag if it goes in the comments. You could hazard a guess? It might just be right!

Comment: EDIT: Changed 1 word in OP to improve accuracy of statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Cell

I contain what's in a bleaker war,

> As pointed out by M Oehm in the comments, "bleaker war" is an anagram of "lawbreaker" so this may be referring to a prison cell which would contain such an individual.
>  Alternatively, a *sleeper cell* is a group of agents that remain inactive for a long period and a cell is a group forming a nucleus of political activity, such as a terrorist cell.

Figures entered and values stored.

> A cell is a unit in a database table and is a basic unit in flash memory.

Within your eyes I keep the watch running,

> Your eye contains cone cells which are responsible for colour vision - they keep the "watch" running (a play on words).

With light I can rise if I let the sun in.

> A photocell is a device which uses the photoelectric effect to generate current. Alternatively, this could be referring to photosynthetic cells in plants.

Stored within all that's alive,

> A cell is the functional basic unit of life.

When lost and replaced you might just survive.

> Cell regeneration is the process of renewal, restoration, and growth that makes genomes, cells, organisms, and ecosystems resilient to natural fluctuations or events that cause disturbance or damage.

Distances covered without moving a fraction,

> I think this refers to *cell phones* (mobile phones), instant communication with far away places.

It's time to break off and take our own action.

> I think this refers to a Clandestine cell structure.

Comment: That looks promising. Perhaps it's a bit of a stretch, but bleaker war is an anagram of lawbreaker, who might be put in a cell.

Comment: Wow, that's really clever.

Comment: @hexomino Well done hexomino. :) The bleaker war was indeed "law breaker" contained within a prison cell. Figures entered, values stored was a spreadsheet cell. The watch was both eye cell functioning and also a wrist watch cell battery. The lost and replaced referred to both cell regeneration and blood replacement/transfusion. Distances covered was indeed a cell phone. Great work!

Comment: Well done to @MOehm too for spotting the anagram. :)